# How to separate Model in another project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've build a simple MVC Asp.NET application that is connected to a database in sql server, using entity framework I've build the controllers and the views.

Now I'm supposed to separate the Model in another project in the same solution.

I've created the project and connected the new model to the new project.

Now, how to reference that project in the controllers and views project? how to add the dll?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1** : Right Click on 'References' of MVC Project

**Step 2** : Select Add References..

**Step 3** : From Left Side Menu select Project > Solution

**Step 4** : Check Your Project

**Step 5** : Click Ok